# How to do a simple text input bind in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am trying to [do a simple binding from an Angular2](http://plnkr.co/edit/D7iTm5Z0P37y9oFkppN6?p=preview) component to the template. My template code looks like this...

```html
<textarea class="left-side" #newLeft (keyup)="enterLeftText($event, newLeft)"></textarea>

<textarea class="right-side">{{leftText}}</textarea>
```

Then in my component I have the following...

```js
enterLeftText($event, newLeft) {
  this.leftText = newLeft.value;
}
```

The problem is that newLeft is always undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like `textarea` doesn't support the `#binding` notation. Maybe not implemented yet, you'll need to create you own directive to watch for events and update the model

Comment: changed it to input http://plnkr.co/edit/dtbDwneFFIiTazjiF7Li?p=preview still no luck

Comment: you're right, the error was elsewhere, see my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You found an interesting bug, as it seems we cannot have an uppercase in a `#id` binding.

Simply replacing `newLeft` with `newleft` will solve your problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ngqd0cUXyxsgBKOBSr9S?p=preview

---

**UPDATE**: in fact it appears that the id should be dash-noted and the variable is camel case, as it is the case on Angular 1 when binding attributes.

So the real answer to your problem is to write `#new-left`:

```
<textarea class="left-side" #new-left (keyup)="enterLeftText($event, newLeft)"></textarea>
```

Comment: crazy syntax =) in comparison to aurelia's `<textarea class="left-side" value.bind="leftText"></textarea>`

Comment: @arebutuv that syntax is not equivalent to the code given. He wants to execute a function on key up.

Comment: Templates are now camelCase (since late beta) and `#newLeft` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When using "#new-left" I get an Exception

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors: "-" is
>   not allowed in variable names

The solution with camelCased variable names works fine now for me.